# Interop.Powerpoint equivalent of Interop.Word.Application.Visiblity = off

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word, powerpoint, office-interop

If I want to create a word document in C# using `Interop.Word`, I can create the document without ever opening the program:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application wordApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
wordApp.Visibile = false;
```

I'm trying to find an equivalent when using Interop.Powerpoint, but I have been unable to find the appropriate property.

Any help would be much appreciated.

**EDIT**

Sorry, my question was not clear. I have tried:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Powerpoint.Application pptApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Powerpoint.Application();
pptApp.Visible = Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse;
```

However, I received the following error:

> Application (unknown member) : Invalid request.  Hiding the application window is not allowed.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff745566%28v=office.15%29.aspx

Comment: What Office version do you have installed on the PC? The [Visible](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff745566%28v=office.15%29.aspx) property was introduced with PowerPoint 2010.

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev It's for Office 2010. I ended up just doing everything with OpenXML instead.

Answer (score 3):

You can prevent from showing the window while opening the Presentation:

```
pptApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Powerpoint.Application();
pptApp.Presentations.Open(fileName, WithWindow:Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse);
```

I know you already utilized Open XML, but maybe someone else will need this.

Comment: 3 years later someone needed this! Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

MChmurski's answer inspired me but when I was trying it doesn't work as expected.

The signature for Presentations.Open() is as following:

```
Presentation Open(
    string FileName,
    MsoTriState ReadOnly,
    MsoTriState Untitled,
    MsoTriState WithWindow
)
```

I think we'd be set the last TriState option instead of the 2nd. So I changed it as following and it works perfectly:

```
var objApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Application();
var objPres = objApp.Presentations.Open(filePath, MsoTriState.msoTrue, MsoTriState.msoTrue, MsoTriState.msoFalse);
```